# Estimating Holt-Winters smoothing coefficients in Java

Tags: java, statistics, time-series

I'm working on a system written in Java which is able to perform forecasts using history data. The algorithm being used is a Java port of [this Holt-Winters implementation](http://adorio-research.org/wordpress/?p=1230) (mul­ti­plica­tive sea­son­al­ity).

I have several time series that we would like to analyse and we need different smoothing coefficients for those time series. The algorithm seems to work really well at the moment, the only problem is that how to determine the most sensible values for the smoothing coefficients (alpha, beta, gamma).

I know that I need some sort of non-linear optimization but I am not a mathematician at all so I'm a bit lost among all those theories and concepts.

**EDIT**:

I have a lot of different time series to analyse, I'd like to know if there is a standard/good enough technique (library would be better) for calculating the smoothing parameters that I should give to the Holt-Winters algorithm.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you looked into [JMulTi](http://www.jmulti.de/)?

[This SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/950004/java-library-to-do-time-series-analysis) might be very relevant to you.

Anyone looking into Holt-Winters should definitely check out [Prof. Hyndman's site](http://robjhyndman.com/forecasting/).
He is a domain expert and also the creator of the `forecast()` library in R.

You said you wanted to understand this technique better. The good news is that Hyndman is writing a textbook which is available free for us to check out. The specific chapter on Holt-winters is at: http://otexts.com/fpp/7/5/

I know you wanted it in Java, but if at all R is an option, you should give it a try. (Some people recommend writing from R and reading it into your Java program.)

**UPDATE:**

If it is the initial HW parameters that you care about, I can only think of the `ets` package which implements a **maximum likelihood** search to arrive at the parameters. If you find no Java implementation, your best bet might be to use [JRI (rJava)](http://www.rforge.net/JRI/) and invoke `ets` or `HoltWinters` from inside that.

Hope that helps.

Comment: thanks for your answer, I know Prof. Hyndman's work, almost everything I found redirects me to his site. The point is that I already have a Holt-Winters impl working, what I'd like to know is how can I non-linear optimization to calculate the smoothing parameters for the HW algo

Comment: updated my response to emphasize finding good initial values for the smoothing parameters α, β, and Γ.

Comment: I'm going to accept this as it seems to be a reasonable answer, even though is not what I expected

Answer (score 3):

You can make use of the **Nelder Mead Optimizer** implemented by Apache (SimplexOptimizer)

```
double[] dataPoints = {
            141, 53, 78, 137, 182, 161, 177,
            164, 70, 67, 129, 187, 161, 136,
            167, 57, 61, 159, 158, 152, 169,
            181, 65, 60, 146, 186, 180, 181,
            167, 70, 62, 170, 193, 167, 176,
            149, 69, 68, 168, 181, 200, 179,
            181, 83, 72, 157, 188, 193, 173,
            184, 61, 59, 158, 158, 143, 208,
            172, 82, 86, 158, 194, 193, 159
};

NelderMeadOptimizer.Parameters op = NelderMeadOptimizer.optimize(dataPoints, 7);
op.getAlpha(); 
op.getBeta(); 
op.getGamma();
```

Now you need the NelderMeadOptimizer:

```
import org.apache.commons.math3.analysis.MultivariateFunction;
import org.apache.commons.math3.optim.InitialGuess;
import org.apache.commons.math3.optim.MaxEval;
import org.apache.commons.math3.optim.MaxIter;
import org.apache.commons.math3.optim.PointValuePair;
import org.apache.commons.math3.optim.nonlinear.scalar.GoalType;
import org.apache.commons.math3.optim.nonlinear.scalar.MultivariateFunctionMappingAdapter;
import org.apache.commons.math3.optim.nonlinear.scalar.ObjectiveFunction;
import org.apache.commons.math3.optim.nonlinear.scalar.noderiv.NelderMeadSimplex;
import org.apache.commons.math3.optim.nonlinear.scalar.noderiv.SimplexOptimizer;

import java.util.List;

public class NelderMeadOptimizer {

    // configuration
    private static final double minValueForOptimizedParameters = 0.001;
    private static final double maxValueForOptimizedParameters = 0.99;
    private static final double simplexRelativeThreshold = 0.0001;
    private static final double simplexAbsoluteThreshold = 0.0001;

    private static final double DEFAULT_LEVEL_SMOOTHING = 0.01;
    private static final double DEFAULT_TREND_SMOOTHING = 0.01;
    private static final double DEFAULT_SEASONAL_SMOOTHING = 0.01;

    private static final int MAX_ALLOWED_NUMBER_OF_ITERATION = 1000;
    private static final int MAX_ALLOWED_NUMBER_OF_EVALUATION = 1000;

    /**
     *
     * @param dataPoints the observed data points
     * @param seasonLength the amount of data points per season
     * @return the optimized parameters
     */
    public static Parameters optimize(double[] dataPoints, int seasonLength) {
        MultivariateFunctionMappingAdapter costFunc = getCostFunction(dataPoints, seasonLength);
        double[] initialGuess = getInitialGuess(dataPoints, seasonLength);
        double[] optimizedValues = optimize(initialGuess, costFunc);
        double alpha = optimizedValues[0];
        double beta = optimizedValues[1];
        double gamma = optimizedValues[2];
        return new Parameters(alpha, beta, gamma);
    }

    /**
     * Optimizes parameters using the Nelder-Mead Method
     * @param initialGuess initial guess / state required for Nelder-Mead-Method
     * @param costFunction which defines that the Mean Squared Error has to be minimized
     * @return the optimized values
     */
    private static double[] optimize(double[] initialGuess, MultivariateFunctionMappingAdapter costFunction) {
        double[] result;

        SimplexOptimizer optimizer = new SimplexOptimizer(simplexRelativeThreshold, simplexAbsoluteThreshold);

        PointValuePair unBoundedResult = optimizer.optimize(
                GoalType.MINIMIZE,
                new MaxIter(MAX_ALLOWED_NUMBER_OF_ITERATION),
                new MaxEval(MAX_ALLOWED_NUMBER_OF_EVALUATION),
                new InitialGuess(initialGuess),
                new ObjectiveFunction(costFunction),
                new NelderMeadSimplex(initialGuess.length));

        result = costFunction.unboundedToBounded(unBoundedResult.getPoint());
        return result;
    }


    /**
     * Defines that the Mean Squared Error has to be minimized
     * in order to get optimized / good parameters for alpha, betta and gamma.
     * It also defines the minimum and maximum values for the parameters to optimize.
     * @param dataPoints the data points
     * @param seasonLength the amount of data points per season
     * @return a cost function  {@link MultivariateFunctionMappingAdapter} which
     * defines that the Mean Squared Error has to be minimized
     * in order to get optimized / good parameters for alpha, betta and gamma
     */
    private static MultivariateFunctionMappingAdapter getCostFunction(final double[] dataPoints, final int seasonLength) {

        MultivariateFunction multivariateFunction = new MultivariateFunction() {
            @Override
            public double value(double[] point) {
                double alpha = point[0];
                double beta = point[1];
                double gamma = point[2];

                if (beta >= alpha) {
                    return Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY;
                }

                List<Double> predictedValues = TripleExponentialSmoothing.getSmoothedDataPointsWithPredictions(dataPoints, seasonLength, alpha, beta, gamma, 1);

                predictedValues.remove(predictedValues.size()-1);

                double meanSquaredError = getMeanSquaredError(dataPoints, predictedValues);
                return meanSquaredError;
            }
        };

        double[][] minMax = getMinMaxValues();
        return new MultivariateFunctionMappingAdapter(multivariateFunction, minMax[0], minMax[1]);
    }

    /**
     * Generates an initial guess/state required for Nelder-Mead-Method.
     * @param dataPoints the data points
     * @param seasonLength the amount of data points per season
     * @return array containing initial guess/state required for Nelder-Mead-Method
     */
    public static double[] getInitialGuess(double[] dataPoints, int seasonLength){
        double[] initialGuess = new double[3];
        initialGuess[0] = DEFAULT_LEVEL_SMOOTHING;
        initialGuess[1] = DEFAULT_TREND_SMOOTHING;
        initialGuess[2] = DEFAULT_SEASONAL_SMOOTHING;
        return initialGuess;
    }

    /**
     * Get minimum and maximum values for the parameters alpha (level coefficient),
     * beta (trend coefficient) and gamma (seasonality coefficient)
     * @return array containing all minimum and maximum values for the parameters alpha, beta and gamma
     */
    private static double[][] getMinMaxValues() {
        double[] min = new double[3];
        double[] max = new double[3];
        min[0] = minValueForOptimizedParameters;
        min[1] = minValueForOptimizedParameters;
        min[2] = minValueForOptimizedParameters;

        max[0] = maxValueForOptimizedParameters;
        max[1] = maxValueForOptimizedParameters;
        max[2] = maxValueForOptimizedParameters;
        return new double[][]{min, max};
    }


    /**
     * Compares observed data points from the past and predicted data points
     * in order to calculate the Mean Squared Error (MSE)
     * @param observedData the observed data points from the past
     * @param predictedData the predicted data points
     * @return the Mean Squared Error (MSE)
     */
    public static double getMeanSquaredError(double[] observedData, List<Double> predictedData){
        double sum = 0;

        for(int i=0; i<observedData.length; i++){
            double error = observedData[i] - predictedData.get(i);
            double sumSquaredError = error * error; // SSE
            sum += sumSquaredError;
        }

        return sum / observedData.length;
    }

    /**
     * Holds the parameters alpha (level coefficient), beta (trend coefficient)
     * and gamma (seasonality coefficient) for Triple Exponential Smoothing.
     */
    public static class Parameters {
        public final double alpha;
        public final double beta;
        public final double gamma;

        public Parameters(double alpha, double beta, double gamma) {
            this.alpha = alpha;
            this.beta = beta;
            this.gamma = gamma;
        }

        public double getAlpha() {
            return alpha;
        }

        public double getBeta() {
            return beta;
        }

        public double getGamma() {
            return gamma;
        }
    };
}
```